Possibly incorrect answer for local maximum at Wolfram Alpha
Consider a function $f(x) = x + \sin(x)$. There is no global maxima or global minima for this function. I found the critical points are
$$ x = (2n-1)\pi \qquad n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
So, $x = \pi$ is one of the critical points. But, its neither a local maxima nor a local minima since $f(\pi - 0.1) < f(\pi) < f(\pi + 0.1) $.
But, I got the following output from Wolfram Alpha

So, why Wolfram is showing $x = \pi$ as a local maximum ?

it seems to register a few of the points $(2n - 1) \pi$ for positive $n$ as local maximums (it registers $n = 1$, $n = 2$ but not $n = 3$), but not all. So I reckon it's some quirk with how WA is trying to compute the extrema (it might be with some numerical method that isn't finding the derivative).

@George, it seems WA is not completely reliable as its obviously giving incorrect result here

yeah it makes mistakes sometimes

It's not saying that the maximum is attained at $x=\pi$ but at some point that agrees with $\pi$ on the first 4 decimals. This I would interpret as an indicator that numerical methods were used with a not so strict accuracy requirement, as was mentioned already in a comment above. When WA finds something to be $\pi$ it explicitly writes it like $\pi$, e.g. compare with the result of "solve D(x+sinx)"

Wolfram's answer has taken into account that the points  $(2n+1)\pi$ are inflection points  (odd order and first and second derivative are zero) . Also the points $3\pi, 5\pi, 7\pi$ and analogous are local maximum.

Although its a bit offtopic, just to mention that your argument cannot disprove $f$ does not have local extrema at $\pi$ (at a rigorous manner), use multiderivative test is easier.
